# Help with proving bezout's theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

[image: BEzout]

> Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$ where $d=\gcd(a,b)$ and $c$ is a multiple of $d$. Suppose that $(x=x_0, y=y_0)$ is one particular integer solution to
>   $$ax+by=c.$$
>   Then the complete set of integer solutions is
>   $$S=\left\{ \left(x=x_0+k\cdot \frac bd, y=y_0-k\cdot \frac ad \right) \mid k\in\mathbb Z \right\}$$

I cannot figure out how to prove this Theorem!! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Let $\gcd(a,b)=d$. Then an integer c has the form $ax+by$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ if and only if c is a multiple of d. Once you prove this, Bezout's Theorem follows.